# Number of symmetries of a regular n-gon

Tags: group-theory

My book states that there are $2n$ symmetries of a regular $n$-gon, but how come it isn't $2n-1$. Aren't you counting the original $n$-gon twice if you say it's $2n$? If you simply rotate $n$ times, you end up with the original $n$-gon. So why are we counting the symmetry beloning to the $n$th rotation as well?

Comment: Connecting from one point diametrically to the other point gives $n$ symmetry lines. But you can do the same from a midpoint of a side to the midpoint of the side across. That's another $n$ symmetry lines

Comment: The original object before rotation or reflection is considered to have been transformed under an identity symmetry.

Comment: @Ed_4434, so it's just convention?

Comment: Let $\theta=2\pi/n$. Either count $0.\dot \theta$, $1\cdot\theta$, up to $(n-1)\cdot\theta$ (that gives $n$) or $1\cdot\theta$, $2\cdot\theta$, up to $n\cdot\theta$.

Comment: @Matthew:  In one sense, it is convention that you count the identity symmetry.  In another, we want the symmetries to form a group and the group needs an identity element, so it is more useful to use that definition.

Comment: The group you are reading about is called $D_n$ the "dihedral group" of an $n$-gon. For a group to be formed, one of the axioms is that there must exist an element $r_0 \in D_n$ such that for any $a \in D_n$, the composition $r_0 \circ a = a \circ r_0 = a$. In English, $r_0$ is simply a symmetry of the $n$-gon which leaves it alone. Any composition of an element with $r_0$ will result in the element itself.